# Printing Matlab Figures Using -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash

Tags: plot, maps, matlab, matlab-figure

I am using Matlab's Mapping Toolbox to create and print a conically projected figure of North America. When I run the code inside the IDE the plots are printed and saved correctly, but when running the same script on the command line using -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash I run into a very strange problem.

During the print() function call, Matlab stops running the script without any error, warning, or crash log. Matlab does not actually crash...it just stops executing my code. Printing a figure without a display is suppose to be possible [according to this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1KY74I/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1KY74I).

Other people have come across a similar issue and have asked about it on the [MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/310157).

[Here is some code to reproduce this problem.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8058705/plot_test.zip)

So far, no one has come up with a solution. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

Here is some self contained code to reproduce the problem. I have tested on both R2011b and R2012a.

```
figure(1)
axesm eckert4; framem; gridm; axis off; tightmap

load geoid
contourfm(geoid, geoidrefvec, -120:20:100, 'LineStyle', 'none');

coast = load('coast');
geoshow(coast.lat, coast.long, 'Color', 'black')

contourcbar

print('-f1','-dpng','-r200','-painters', 'example');
```

Comment: Can you post a [short, self contained example](http://sscce.org/), rather than requiring us to download a zip file of your source code before we can try to answer your question. Also, linking to code is generally a bad idea, since if that link becomes broken (say you stop using dropbox) then this question may be pretty useless.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the plots I am producing are part of a much larger software package, but I will try to come up with some self contained code to reproduce this.

Comment: @GPSmaster: I assume you are using a Linux machine. I have no problem exporting the figure in MATLAB R2012a on WinXP (although it warns you not to use the painters renderer)

Comment: Yes I am using linux. I have tried this on REHL5 and ubuntu 10.10. Just to clarify, you ran the code from the command line using -nodisplay -nodesktop and -nosplash options? Because I am also able to export the figure if I run the same code in the IDE.

Comment: @GPSmaster: yes. I saved your code as `myscript.m` then ran: `matlab -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -nosplash -r "myscript; quit"` (`noFigureWindows` is the Windows equivalent of Unix-only `nodisplay` option)

Comment: although the colorbar does not show correctly (displayed all in white)

Answer (score 2):

The following warnings appear if you run MATLAB from scripts using, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r myCode > myLog.log &
exit
```

.

```
[Warning: Objects of graph2d.lineseries class exist - not clearing this class or
any of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of scribe.legend class exist - not clearing this class or any
of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of graphics.panbehavior class exist - not clearing this class
or any of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of graphics.zoombehavior class exist - not clearing this class
or any of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of graphics.rotate3dbehavior class exist - not clearing this
class or any of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of graphics.datacursorbehavior class exist - not clearing this
class or any of its superclasses] 
[Warning: Objects of graphics.ploteditbehavior class exist - not clearing this
class or any of its superclasses]
```

The problem is that the matlab code would like to display a figure, plot or something else, but the option `-nodisplay` prohibits it. I solved this problem by simply add the following lines to my code `set(gcf, 'visible','off');` and at the end `close gcf; clear gcf;`. Now the plot legend was as in the first plot without shift and I got no warning.

Answer (score 1):

I've come to the conclusion that this problem is not solvable, and is a bug.

The closest I've gotten to solving the problem is using the following code from the shell:

```
$ matlab -nosplash -nodisplay < makefigure.m
```

makefigure.m:

```
plot(randn(100,1)); 
set(gca,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.13 0.11 0.775 0.815]);
set(gcf,'Units','pixels','Position',[4 4 1200 900]);  %# Modify figure size
hgexport(gcf,'myfig.png',...
    hgexport('factorystyle'),'Format','png');
```

Which will output a png file 'myfig.png' of 1200x900 pixels. Unfortunately, while the image is the size I want, the graph itself is still the small size. I'm not certain of the cause of this, but I believe it has something to do with the fact that Matlab is object oriented and that the axes are *supposed* to be linked to the figure size (that's what the 'Position' variable for gca is normalized to). For whatever reason, this doesn't happen specifically when the display is turned off. I doubt this will be addressed anytime soon by Mathwoks, and I can't blame them since the vast majority of Matlab users use the GUI.

The one potential clue that could help anyone with the means to fix this is that it gives an error when running on the command line:

```
Warning: Objects of graph2d.lineseries class exist - not clearing this class
or any of its super-classes
```

I searched for a solution but just found more questions. My suspicion is that if someone can figure out what that means, you can fix this issue. For now, I will once again go back to python because with Matlab I just spend hours dealing with inconveniences instead of being productive.

Edit:
In case it helps, this is Matlab 2012a on
Linux ... 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 #1 SMP ... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux